# PHP - Pass array values to mysql query and fetch the result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$dataSet = Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [quantity] => 22 [sr_no] => 71 [batch_id] =>5 [inq_id] => 91 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [quantity] => 35 [sr_no] => 72 [batch_id] => [inq_id] => 92 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [quantity] => 20 [sr_no] => 69 [batch_id] => [inq_id] => 90 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [quantity] => 45 [sr_no] => 75 [batch_id] => 6 [inq_id] => 94 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [quantity] => 15 [sr_no] => 70 [batch_id] => 6 [inq_id] => 90 ) 
)
```

I've the above array from which I need to get each sr_no, batch_id and need to check whether the combination is present (eg. the first row sr_no => 71 & batch_id => 5) in a table ( part_list ). I've tried the below code but it is fetching all. Ready to implement if there is any better approach also.

```
$keyedExistingPartRows = array_column(
    $this->db
        ->where_in('batch_id', array_column($dataSet, 'batch_id'))
        ->where_in('sr_no', array_column($dataSet, 'sr_no'))
        ->get('part_list')
        ->result_array(),
    null,
    'sr_no'
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two separate where_in with the full arrays of the column values, make little sense here to begin with - that does not check for the “combination” you are looking for at all. The WHERE clause you effectively need in the end, is  something like `WHERE (sr_no = 71 AND batch_id = 5) OR (sr_no = 75 AND batch_id = 6) OR …`

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the reply. Can u plz explain how to implement it?

Comment: You also have to account for your entries that don't have the batch id. Is that a legitimate combination you'd want to look for?

Comment: @El_Vanja Yes, some entries don't have batch_id. So need to check the combination of sr_no & batch_id even if the batch_id is empty.

Comment: Is the batch id an empty string in the database in those cases and not `null`?

Comment: @El_Vanja Tinytext is the datatype for batch_id and not null

Comment: In that case you can literally use a loop to add an `or_where` to your query object for every combination.

Comment: @El_Vanja Can you post the answer if possible?

Comment: I can't test it as I don't have a Codeigniter project set up and I don't like to post answers with code I haven't tested. Try to write it, it's a simple foreach. Loop your array, place a `$this->db->or_where` call inside the loop and the rest of it (`get` and `result_array`) outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to check for both `sr_no` and `batch_id`.
If you are willing to use raw SQL query you can first concat the two columns and then provide the array for that concatinated column and find the desired result.

please try this

```
$temp_Arr = [];

foreach($dataSet as $val){
    $temp_Arr[] = $val['sr_no']."-".$val['batch_id'];    
}
$sr_no_and_batch_id = "('".implode("', '", $temp_Arr)."')";
//echo $sr_no_and_batch_id;

$sql="SELECT * FROM `part_list` WHERE CONCAT(sr_no, '-', batch_id) IN $sr_no_and_batch_id";    
$query = $this->db->query($SQL);
return $query->result_array();
```